Check if number entered is already in a table using jQuery
I have an HTML web page which allows a user to enter multiple rows of numbers. I need to add a validation check to check the number entered OR changed does not already exist in the table.
A row is added to the table on button click using the below jQuery:
$('table tbody').append(
'<tr>' +
'<td>' +
'<input name="Associated Numbers" class="form-control telNumberInput"' +
' type="text" minlength="11" maxlength="11" placeholder="Enter telephone number" />' +
'<div name="tel-num-error-msg" class="text-danger" style="display: none"></div>' +
'</td>' +
'<td>' +
'<select name="Tel Number Action" class="form-control">' +
'<option value="" selected hidden>Select an option</option>' +
'<option value="One">Test 1</option>' +
'<option value="Two">Test 2</option>' +
'</select>' +
'</td>' +
'<td>' +
'<button name="del-tel-num-btn" class="btn btn-danger bin-icon" type="button">' +
'<i class="bi bi-trash3"></i>' +
'</button>' +
'</td>' +
'</tr>'
)

The above code works fine, but I need to do is on blur or focusout of the input with the focus, I need it to check that the telephone number is not already listed, but I can not get it to work.
This is all the code I have tried but it always displays my error message.
The validation scenario is:

It has more than one row in the table
The input that has been changed (whether updating an existing inputs value or adding the number in the new empty input)

Initial

Button clicked

This is the jQuery I have been trying to use but whenever I have 2 rows in the table it drops in my if and displays the error message even when the telephone number isn't already listed.
I have tried using array and various if statements. It is probably easier than I'm thinking but I'm in a hole and "code blind" and can't think of the code to do it correctly.
$(document).on('focusout', 'input[name="Associated Numbers"]', function() {
// $(document).on('blur', 'input[name="Associated Numbers"]', function() {
    const enteredNum = this.value
    let rowCount = 0
    let errorMsgTxt = ''
    let existingNumbers = []
    // let rowIndex = $(this).closest('#associated-num-tbl tbody tr').index()

    // $('#associated-num-tbl tbody tr').each(function() {
    //     rowCount++
    //
    //     // if (rowIndex !== $(this).index() && rowCount > 1) {
    //     if (rowCount > 1) {
    //         $(this).find('input').each(function () {        //
    //             if (enteredNum === this.value && rowIndex !== $(this).index()) {
    //                 errorMsgTxt = 'has already been added'
    //
    //                 return false
    //             }
    //         })
    //     }
    // })

    $('#associated-num-tbl tbody tr').each(function() {
        rowCount++

        $(this).find('input').each(function () {
            existingNumbers.push(this.value)
        })
    })

    if (rowCount > 1) {
        $.each(existingNumbers, function (i, number) {
            if (number === enteredNum && number !== '') {
            // if (number === enteredNum) {
                $(this).closest('tr').find($('div[name="assoc-num-error-msg"]')).text('Number has already been added').show(0, function () {
                    $(this).closest('td').find('input').trigger('focus')
                })

               return false
            }
        });
    }
});


As you can see the number does not exist in the table.

It's considered bad practice to deduce existing values (your numbers) by parsing the DOM (unless you're scraping an external website). That aside, assoc-num-error-msg != tel-num-error-msg, also, pushing inside a $(this).find('input').each(function () { might lead to false positives. There's also no need to rowCount++ if you already pushing to some array the retrieved numbers. Just loop that array of collected numbers.

$('table tbody').append( don't. Use the exact table's ID instead #associated-num-tbl tbody

So the fix was to use the index. So I got the table row index of the input changed then in the following each if the index matched the variable stored index number then ignore it
if (rowCount > 1) {
   $.each(existingNumbers, function (i, number) {
      if (number === enteredNum && i !== rowIndex) {
         $(this).closest('tr').find($('div[name="assoc-num-error-msg"]')).text('Number ' + errorMsgTxt).show(0, function () {
            $(this).closest('td').find('input').trigger('focus')
        })
      }
   });
}

Full JQuery workout
$(document).on('blur', 'input[name="Associated Numbers"]', function() {
   const enteredNum = this.value
   let rowIndex = $(this).closest('#associated-num-tbl tbody tr').index()
   let existingNumbers = []
   let rowCount = 0

   $('#associated-num-tbl tbody tr').each(function() {
      rowCount++

      $(this).find('input').each(function () {
         if (this.value !== '') {
            existingNumbers.push(this.value)
         }
      })
   })

   if (rowCount > 1) {
      $.each(existingNumbers, function (i, number) {
         if (number === enteredNum && i !== rowIndex) {
            $(this).closest('tr').find($('div[name="assoc-num-error-msg"]')).text('Number ' + errorMsgTxt).show(0, function () {
               $(this).closest('td').find('input').trigger('focus')
            })

            return false
         }
      })
    }
})


As I told you, there's no need to  if (rowCount > 1) { because it there's no items in $.each(existingNumbers the each would exit immediately. So rowCount  is useless.

I've tried the logic and the code was mentioned below.
Here I'm using only one loop .each to find the duplicate and show the error message on appropriate tr. May be it'll helpful to you.
$(document).on('blur', 'input[name="Associated Numbers"]', function() {
   const enteredNum = this.value;
   const rowIndex = $(this).closest('#associated-num-tbl tbody tr').index();
   let isDuplicate = false;

   $('#associated-num-tbl tbody tr').each(function() {
       const inputValue = $(this).find('input[name="Associated Numbers"]').val();

       if (inputValue && inputValue === enteredNum && $(this).index() !== rowIndex) {
           isDuplicate = true;
           return false; // Exit the loop on finding a duplicate
       }
   });

   if (isDuplicate) {
       $(this).closest('tr').find('div[name="tel-num-error-msg"]')
           .text('Number has already been added')
           .show(0, function() {
               $(this).closest('td').find('input').trigger('focus');
           });
   } else {
       $(this).closest('tr').find('div[name="tel-num-error-msg"]').hide();
   }
});

